# Regex to pull match from ordered list

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Given this string of text:

```
$myString = '<details class="myEl" open="open">
        <summary>In this article</summary>
        <ol>
                <li><a href="post-slug/">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-slug/2/">Title for the second page</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-slug/3/">Title for the third page</a></li>
        </ol>
</details>';
```

What would the regex be to pull "Title for the second page", if I'm given that the match to search is "/2/"?

I'd also need to pull "Title for the third page" if the match was "/3/", so I need a generic regex that will pull the string between > and < after the match.

Comment: what is your match? how are you getting it?

Comment: The match will always be a number between two forward slashes "/n/". So I need to start there and look for the string between > and < following the match.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
preg_match('!\/' . $pageNo . '\/">(.*?)\<\/a\>!', $myString, $matches);
$pageTitle = $matches[1];
```

Edit:
Page 1 should work with this one:

```
preg_match('!\/' . ($pageNo == 1 ? ($pageNo . '\/') : '') . '">(.*?)\<\/a\>!', $myString, $matches);
$pageTitle = $matches[1];
```

Comment: It would be better to add full start of the a tag to limit risk of false positives. But this should work and is valid reply vote up

Answer (score 0):

I guess it better to use XPath to make such thing, one example would be:

```php
$str = '<details class="myEl" open="open">
        <summary>In this article</summary>
        <ol>
                <li><a href="post-slug/">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-slug/2/">Title for the second page</a></li>
                <li><a href="post-slug/3/">Title for the third page</a></li>
        </ol>
</details>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
var_dump($xml->xpath('//details/ol/li/a[contains(@href, "/3/")]'));
```

But regarding to regex, the following regex could do the work:

```php
preg_match_all('@<li><a href="post-slug/3/">((?:(?!<\/a>).)+)</a></li>@', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Regexp will be way faster than loading the string with simplexml

Comment: I'm not talking about performance. Just sharing ways to extract desired information.

Comment: Ok but the question was about regexp and you guess xpath would be better. This is not true in performance nor regarding the op's question. +your solution only work for index 3 not in other cases

Comment: I thought an example would be fair enough for a developer to implement the rest as him want. But looks like one are seeking for implemented solution instead of knowledge to do by himself.

Comment: It's ok and welcome to propose alternative. But i just wanted to point you that your guess was incorrect ( saying "another way could be" instead of "i guess it better" is totally differents things). Also your reply was and is still incomplete. I think i was perhaps a little rude to you by downvoting edit your answer and i will remove it